# Comando SQL em String MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, procedure

Estou fazendo uma procedure que guarda um select em uma variavel varchar. Agora preciso executar esse comando sql, como faço isso?
Estou usando MySql.
Procedure:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure eixos_caminhao (in numeroEixos int)
declare comando varchar(500);
    set comando = 'select classe, velocidade, date(data) as data, pesoEixo1, pesoEixo2';
    if (numeroEixos > 2) set comando = concat(comando, ', pesoEixo3');
    if (numeroEixos > 3) set comando = concat(comando, ', pesoEixo4');
    if (numeroEixos > 4) set comando = concat(comando, ', pesoEixo5');
    if (numeroEixos > 5) set comando = concat(comando, ', pesoEixo6');
    if (numeroEixos > 6) set comando = concat(comando, ', pesoEixo7');
    if (numeroEixos > 7) set comando = concat(comando, ', pesoEixo8');
    if (numeroEixos > 8) set comando = concat(comando, ', pesoEixo9');
    set comando = concat(comando. ' from tb_vbv');
end$$
delimiter;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use os comandos `PREPARE` e `EXECUTE`:

```
PREPARE myquery FROM comando;
EXECUTE myquery;
```

Podes dar uma pesquisada em mais *links* [como este](https://tableless.com.br/prepared-statements-no-mysql/).

```
delimiter $$
create procedure eixos_caminhao (in numeroEixos int)
begin
    set @comando := 'select classe, velocidade, date(data) as data, pesoEixo1, pesoEixo2';
    if (numeroEixos > 2) set @comando:= concat(@comando, ', pesoEixo3');
    if (numeroEixos > 3) set @comando:= concat(@comando, ', pesoEixo4');
    if (numeroEixos > 4) set @comando:= concat(@comando, ', pesoEixo5');
    if (numeroEixos > 5) set @comando:= concat(@comando, ', pesoEixo6');
    if (numeroEixos > 6) set @comando:= concat(@comando, ', pesoEixo7');
    if (numeroEixos > 7) set @comando:= concat(@comando, ', pesoEixo8');
    if (numeroEixos > 8) set @comando:= concat(@comando, ', pesoEixo9');
    set @comando:= concat(@comando, ' from tb_vbv');

    PREPARE myquery FROM @comando;
    EXECUTE myquery;
end;
delimiter;
```

Comment: Isso dentro da minha procedure, né?

Comment: Exato, dentro da _proc_. Vou alterar a resposta pra jogar o código todo!!

Comment: É que está dando um erro de sintaxe:
unexpected 'comando' (identifier)

Comment: ah, preciso colocar depois do end $$, que aliás, esqueci de colocar no codigo

Comment: hmmm, blz.. tb não percebi =p

Comment: não retornou nada, mesmo setando um select simples na variavel

Comment: tá, vou mudar o `concat` porque está usando `.` ao invés de `,` e no set vou usar o `:=`. Se isso não resolver, acho que não vou saber te ajudar =p

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84239/discussion-between-leandro-kojima-and-rlinhares).

Answer (score 2):

Para executar um comando dinâmico dentro de uma `function`, `procedure` ou em `trigger` é necessário preparar a `string` e depois executa-lá.

Por exemplo, para criar uma procedure que soma dois números e retorna o resultado seria mais ou menos assim:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS soma $$ 

CREATE PROCEDURE soma(in valor1 INT(11), in valor2 INT(11))
BEGIN
    PREPARE stmt FROM CONCAT('SELECT ', valor1,' + ', valor2, ' AS resultado');
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END $$

DELIMITER;
```

Para retornar o resultado é só executar algo como:

```
CALL soma(1, 2);
```

Neste caso o retorno será:

```
+---------+
|resultado|
|---------|
|        3|
+---------+
```

Essa mesma função também pode ser alterada de modo que seja passados parâmetros. A vantagem de passar parâmetros é que pode reutilizar a mesma `query` em algum momento dentro da `procedure`.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS soma $$ 

CREATE PROCEDURE soma(in valor1 INT(11), in valor2 INT(11))
BEGIN
    SET @valor1 = valor1, @valor2 = valor2; # É necessário criar essas variáveis antes de utiliza-las no USING
    PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT ? + ? AS resultado';
    EXECUTE stmt USING @valor1, @valor2;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END $$

DELIMITER;
```

Se passado os mesmos parâmetros o retorno será exatamente o mesmo.

Pode ver mais sobre `prepared statments` [aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

**Explicação dos Comandos**

- `PREPARE nome_da_variavel FROM sql`: Neste ponto a `query` esta sendo preparada, ou seja, a variável `nome_da_variavel` irá receber um `statment` com a `query` que foi passada após o `FROM`;
- `EXECUTE nome_da_variavel`: O `EXECUTE` executará o `statment`. Caso tenha parâmetros, após o `statment` deve ser usada a palavra reservada `USING` e após ela, todos os parâmetros separados por virgula.
- `DEALLOCATE PREPARE nome_da_variavel`: O `DEALLOCATE` é usado para liberar a variável, ou seja, após a execução dele, o statment não existirá mais.